# Getting systemctl with Arpwatch to work

Tags: 18.04

Having trouble on 18.04.1 getting arpwatch to start. It seems to work with

. /etc/init.d/arpwatch start but not systemctl start arpwatch

Any ideas?

Comment: what the output of `systemctl status arpwatch` sir?

Comment: Nothing - sorry

Comment: please Verify that the process is running with
`ps -ef|grep arpwatch`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved this, but you need to enable the interface with

```
systemctl enable arpwatch@eth0
```

and then

```
systemctl start arpwatch@eth0
```